# HTML5 Video flashes white before playing?

Tags: css, html, video

I am using HTML5 Video tags to embed an OGG/MP4/OGV video file into my site. The problem is that there's a white box that flashes where the video goes for a split second before it loads. I tried changing the background color of the video element, but it's still showing a white box. Is there any way to prevent this?

my CSS:

```
video {
  background-color:#000;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem with a similar setup i.e. `height:auto` on the video and the parent height not a fixed value. Adding a border to the video seemed to fix the issue. Not sure why but I guess it forces the browser to render the video layout before height is fully calculated.

```
video {
    // ...
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
video {background: transparent;}
```

This should handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a white box flashing between the 'poster' image and the first frame of my 'video'. This might be the same white flash you are talking about.

I solved it in two ways:

1. Use [#t=0.1] after your video source like so:

> ```
> <video id="myVideo" playsinline loop muted onended="resetVideo()">
>             <source src="xxxx.mp4#t=0.1" type="video/mp4">
>             Your browser does not support the video tag.
>         </video>
> ```

where 0.1 is the number of seconds (one-tenth of a second). What this does is place your first frame of the video as the placeholder/thumbnail.

2. Use a background-image property. Now this may not help you since you already tried changing your background-color, but it just might as it did help me solve the problem even when changing the background-color didn't work for me. The nature of when this will work for you depends on the precise situation you are in. In any case, you can use the background-image property to a URL like so:

> ```
> background-image: url("first-frame-image.jpg");
> ```

and then adjust other background properties in order to ensure the background fits over the video. In my case, I used the following background properties:

> ```
> background-repeat: no-repeat;
> background-size: cover;
> background-position: center;
> ```

Hope this helps!